# Select ManagedBy under OU in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this Powershell code

```
$offices = get-qadobject -Type 'organizationalUnit' -SearchRoot 'ou=Test_OU,dc=domain,dc=org'
Foreach($office in $offices)
{
    $line = $office | select Name,Description,ManagedBy
    $line
}
```

It is grabbing everything except for `ManagedBy` which ends up blank. How do I get the email and name of the `ManagedBy` object? The AD object contains this data.

Note there's some Quest (https://jschofield22.wordpress.com/tag/get-qadobject/) use in here, but it's similar to `Get-ADObject`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Base,DC=fabrikam,DC=com" -Properties Description |
  Select-Object DistinguishedName,
    Name,
    Description,
    ManagedBy,
    @{Name="ManagedBy_mail"; Expression={(Get-ADObject $_.ManagedBy -Properties mail).mail}}
```

Comment: No luck there, `ManagedBy` still came out blank.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you certain you are requesting the correct property? (Look at the `Attribute Editor` tab in the ADUC console.)

Comment: Hmm okay. We're using Quest, so adjusted this into using `QADObject`. I'm not sure why it isn't grabbing it when it grabs everything else just fine. I'll have to see if the property is a different name in Quest.

Comment: So you _didn't_ use the `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` command I specified above? In any case, check the actual object attributes and verify you are retrieving the property you think you are.

Comment: No, because I get a `not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` error with that. This script isn't running on a DC which I assume is why, it's running on the Quest server.

Comment: You don't need a server or the Quest cmdlets. All you have to do is install the Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell.